# Regex to identify email forward details

Tags: regex

I'm trying to parse a email string and tries to extract all the forwarder details.

> "Regards\nAnkit Balyan\n\n\n---------- Forwarded message ---------\n\nFrom: John Doe \nDate: Thu, Aug 23, 2018 at 04:00 PM\nSubject: my Email Subject\nTo: Ankit Balyan \n\n\nHi,\n\nThis is for testing purpose\n\n"

It should extract something like below in capturing groups.

```
From Name: John Doe
From Email: john.doe@gmail.com
Date: Thu, Aug 23, 2018 at 04:00 PM
Subject: my Email Subject
```

I've tried something like below

```
(?:\\nFrom: ([^<]*))?(?:<?(.+@[^>]+)>?)?(?:\\nDate: ([^<]*))?(?:\\nSubject: (.+(?=)))?(?:\\nTo: ([^<]*))?(?:<?(.+@[^>]+)>?)
```

Comment: Use [`From:\s*([^<]*)(?:<([^><]+)>)?(?:\nDate:\s*(.+))?(?:\nSubject:\s*(.+))?`](https://regex101.com/r/n7fYaO/1) in the *target environment*.

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew I've also added named grouped as well.  

    ` /From:\s*(?<name>[^<]*)(?:<(?<email>[^><]+)>)?(?:\nDate:\s*(?<date>.+))?(?:\nSubject:\s*(?<subject>.+))?/ `

Comment: Attempting to parse Outlook's bastardized version of email headers is pretty doomed. The real header names are replaced with strings which vary between versions and are translated to other even more random strings in localized versions of the software.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks, but I've not started parsing outlook emails, just did it for gmail for now, I'll try once this is completed.
Still if you can link me to something, most welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
From:\s*(?<name>[^<]*)(?:<(?<email>[^><]+)>)?(?:\nDate:\s*(?<date>.+))?(?:\nSubject:\s*(?<subject>.+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/n7fYaO/2)

[image]

**Details**

- `From:\s*` - `From:` and 0+ whitespaces
- `(?<name>[^<]*)` - Group "name": any 0+ chars other than `<`
- `(?:<(?<email>[^><]+)>)?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of:

  - `<` - a `<` char
  - `(?<email>[^><]+)` - Group "email": any 1+ chars other than `<` and `>`
  - `>` - a `>` char
- `(?:\nDate:\s*(?<date>.+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a newline, `Date:`, 0+ whitespaces, and then Group "date" capturing any 1+ chars other than a newline
- `(?:\nSubject:\s*(?<subject>.+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of a newline, `Subject:`, 0+ whitespaces, and then Group "subject" capturing any 1+ chars other than a newline

Comment: Any way if I can negate [^at] from date capturing group?

Though I can replace that after the regex as well.  
'Thu, Aug 23, 2018 at 2:00'.replace('at', '');

Comment: @AnkitBalyan I think `.replace('at', '')` will be the best approach, as you cannot capture discontinuous texts into a single capture.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.